# How do I calculate the new standard deviation if the original population is unknown?

Tags: php, math, statistics, standard-deviation

Coming [from this question on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/775391/99628) I have the following scenario.

There is a set (`$array`) with arbitrary values, the amount of values in the set (`$n`), it's mean (`$mean`) and standard deviation (`$s`).

```
$array = array(1, 5, 16, 3, ...);
$n = count($array);
$mean = array_sum($array) / count($array);
$s = sd($array);
```

Where the `sd()` function has it's origin on the [PHP comments for the `stats_standard_deviation()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-standard-deviation.php#97369):

```
// Function to calculate square of value - mean
function sd_square($x, $mean) { return pow($x - $mean,2); }

// Function to calculate standard deviation (uses sd_square)    
function sd($array) {
    // square root of sum of squares devided by N-1
    return sqrt(array_sum(array_map("sd_square", $array, array_fill(0,count($array), (array_sum($array) / count($array)) ) ) ) / (count($array)-1) );
}
```

Now the `$array` is dropped and the values aren't available anymore (let's say for reasons of anonymity) but another `$x` value is coming in which shall be calculated within the `$mean` and `$s` (standard deviation).

I try to calculate the new standard deviation by this formular (according to [this answer on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/775398/99628)):

```
function m_reverse($n, $mean, $x) {
    return ( $n * $mean + $x ) / ( $n + 1 );
}

function sd_reverse($s, $n, $x, $mean) {
    return sqrt( 1 / $n * ( ( $n - 1 ) * pow( $s, 2 ) + ( $x - $mean ) ) );
}
```

The `m_reverse()` functions returns the correct new mean. But the `sd_reverse()` function won't. Can anyone figure out, what I've done wrong? Maybe inappropriate usage of paranthesis?

You can find a code example of my implementation here: http://3v4l.org/5mPDp

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling `sd_reverse` maybe one of the inputs if off-by-one?

Comment: I believe that last `$x-$mean` should be squared.

Comment: @Halcyon you can view the whole code here: http://3v4l.org/5mPDp

Comment: @Teepeemm what makes you believe that?

Comment: The answer you were given on math.se is wrong...

Comment: намерение's answer on math.se is wrong; every `(x<sub>i</sub>-mean)` should be squared.  Introduce some intermediate variables to your `sd` function.  You'll find that you're taking the difference from the mean, squaring that, averaging, and then square rooting.  When you add in your next term, you aren't squaring.  But as Joni points out, you also need to use the new mean.  You may find it easier to use the alternative definition of variance, which uses the average of the squares, instead of using the average of the square differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the new standard deviation you need to use both the old and new mean; this gives you [Welford's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm).

```
function sd_reverse($s, $n, $x, $mean, $old_mean) {
    return sqrt( 1 / $n * ( ( $n - 1 ) * pow( $s, 2 ) + ( $x - $mean )*( $x - $old_mean ) ) );
}
```

You can find a very readable C++ implementation of running mean, variance and standard deviation here: http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html